# Event queue cleanup

Tags: c, asynchronous, tcl, eventqueue

In my Tcl extension, a secondary thread is filling the Tcl event queue with events; the events contain pointers to structures with a dynamic life time.

What is the right strategy for ensuring that no events with dangling pointers to de-allocated structures remain in the event queue?  I can prevent the secondary thread from creating new events; currently I call `Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_DONTWAIT)` in a loop till it returns 0 (i.e., event queue is empty) after ensuring no new events can be created and before de-allocating the structure.

Is that the right way to do it?

On a related note, I am unsure of the purpose of `Tcl_ThreadAlert()`: if this is needed after every call to `Tcl_ThreadQueueEvent()`, why isn't the alert included in `Tcl_ThreadQueueEvent()`?

Finally, my code does not call `Tcl_CreateEventSource()`, since it doesn't seem to be  needing a setup nor a check procedure as a second thread is involved.  Is that cause for concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first point, that seems OK to me. It is very much like running `update` at the TCL level.

I'm not sure about the second point, as it isn't part of the API that I have explored a lot. It might be that way to allow multiple events to be scheduled per notification, or because there are other uses for the call, but I really don't know.

On the third point, it sounds fine. I think you never need special event sources just to do inter-thread messaging.